# Boolean FlowState from model is not updating

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel, kotlin-flow

In my view model I have a couple of `StateFlow`

```kotlin
class CalibrateViewModel(context: Context) : AndroidViewModel(context.applicationContext as Application){
    private val _isReady = MutableStateFlow(true)
    val isReady: StateFlow<Boolean> = _isReady.asStateFlow()

    private val _logContent= MutableStateFlow("Ready")
    val logContent: StateFlow<String> = _logContent.asStateFlow()
```

When pressing button the `isReady` state is changing to false as expected:

```kotlin
fun calibrate(){
        _isReady.value = false
       Log.d("ViewModel", "New is ready value: ${isReady.value} (backed property ${_isReady.value}")
       _logContent.value = "Started calibration"
....
```

In the composable I have such code:

```kotlin
fun CalibrateScreen(model: CalibrateViewModel) {
    val isReady by model.isReady.collectAsState()
    val logContent by model.logContent.collectAsState()

    Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(10.dp)) {
        Text("Is ready: $isReady")
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
            onClick = model::calibrate,
            enabled = isReady
        ) {
            Text(text = stringResource(R.string.calibrate))
        }
        Text(
            text = logContent,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(1f)
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        )
```

However the collected variable `isReady` on composable side seems not updating. I still see text "Is ready: true". Why this does not work?

Notice that I also have similar String state `logContent`. But it seems updating fine.